# Facebook messanger missing in UIActivityViewController options

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-messenger

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share some data on different social media options.

I can see `Facebook` but i am unable to see `Facebook messenger`. Does any body have any idea why i doesn't appear in the options list?
I have both `Facebook` and `Facebook messenger` installed in my iPhone.

```
UIActivityViewController * shareViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[activity] applicationActivities:nil];

  if(self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular && self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular) {
    shareViewController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem  = self.shareButton;
  }
  [self presentViewController:shareViewController animated:YES completion:^{

  }];
```

Any help will be great thanks

Comment: were you able to find anything useful ?